# Is this a Pandas bug with notnull() or a fundamental misunderstanding on my part (probably misunderstanding)

Tags: python, pandas, null

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns and default indexing.  The first column is a string and the second is a date. The top date is NaN (though it should be NaT really).

```
index    somestr    date
0        ON         NaN
1        1C         2014-06-11 00:00:00
2        2C         2014-07-09 00:00:00
3        3C         2014-08-13 00:00:00
4        4C         2014-09-10 00:00:00
5        5C         2014-10-08 00:00:00
6        6C         2014-11-12 00:00:00
7        7C         2014-12-10 00:00:00
8        8C         2015-01-14 00:00:00
9        9C         2015-02-11 00:00:00
10       10C        2015-03-11 00:00:00
11       11C        2015-04-08 00:00:00
12       12C        2015-05-13 00:00:00
```

Call this dataframe df.

When I run:

```
df[pd.notnull(df['date'])]
```

I expect the first row to go away. It doesn't.
If I remove the column with string by setting:

```
df=df[['date']]
```

Then apply:

```
df[pd.notnull(df['date'])]
```

then the first row with the null does go away.

Also, the row with the null always goes away if all columns are number/date types.  When a column with a string appears, this problem occurs.

Surely this is a bug, right?  I am not sure if others will be able to replicate this.
This was on my Enthought Canopy for Windows (I am not smart enough for UNIX/Linux command line noise)

Per requests below from Jeff and unutbu:
@ubuntu -

```
df.dtypes
somestr    object
date       object
dtype:  object
```

Also:

```
type(df.iloc[0]['date'])
pandas.tslib.NaTType
```

In the code this column was specifically assigned as pd.NaT
I also do not understand why it says NaN when it should say NaT.  The filtering I used worked fine when I used this toy frame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'somestr' : ['aa', 'bb'], 'date' : [pd.NaT, dt.datetime(2014,4,15)]}, columns=['somestr', 'date'])
```

It should also be noted that although the table above had NaN in the output, the following output NaT:

```
df['date'][0]
NaT
```

Also:

```
pd.notnull(df['date'][0])
False

pd.notnull(df['date'][1])
True
```

but....when evaluating the array, they all came back True - bizarre...

```
np.all(pd.notnull(df['date']))
True
```

@Jeff - this is 0.12. I am stuck with this. The frame was created by concatenating two different frames that were grabbed from database queries using psql. The date and some other float columns were then added by calculations I did. Of course, I filtered to the two relevant columns that made sense here until I pinpointed that the string valued columns were causing problems.

****************  How to Replicate **************

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

print(pd.__version__)
# 0.12.0

df = pd.DataFrame({'somestr': ['aa', 'bb'], 'date': ['cc', 'dd']},
                  columns=['somestr', 'date'])
df['date'].iloc[0] = pd.NaT
df['date'].iloc[1] = pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime(2014, 4, 15))
print(df[pd.notnull(df['date'])])
#   somestr                 date
# 0      aa                  NaN
# 1      bb  2014-04-15 00:00:00

df2 = df[['date']]
print(df2[pd.notnull(df2['date'])])
#                  date
# 1 2014-04-15 00:00:00
```

So, this dataframe originally had all string entries - then the date column was converted to dates with an NaT at the top - note that in the table it is NaN, but when using df.iloc[0]['date'] you do see the NaT.  Using the snippet above, you can see that the filtering by not null is bizarre with and without the somestr column.  Again - this is Enthought Canopy for Windows with Pandas 0.12 and NumPy 1.8.

Comment: To help us replicate the error, please post `df.dtypes`.

Comment: what version of pandas? that looks like a fairly old bug. how did you create this frame?

Comment: @Jeff - I have added the info to the OP at the bottom per posting guidelines.

Comment: @unutbu - I have added the info to the OP at the bottom per posting guidelines.

Comment: Please post `type(df.iloc[0]['date'])`. If it says `str`, I understand the problem...

Comment: @unutbu  pandas.tslib.NaTType

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design, but `NaTType` instances are not (currently) considered a null value by `pd.notnull`. A workaround would be to change the column's dtype to `datetime64[ns]` by setting `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`. Note that you'll need NumPy version 1.7 or higher for [`datetime64`s to behave properly](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-deltas-conversions).

Comment: @unutbu - hmmmm....that works, but I still do not understand why this worked fine without the somestr column. I assume you expected type(o.iloc[0]['date'])
 to remain pandas.tslib.NaTType
 after the cast, BTW. Additional comments in edits above - very relevant I think too - see the parts just above (at)Jeff.

Comment: @unutbu - I have figured out how to replicate for others without needing all of my code.  See the bottom of the OP with the "How To Replicate" section.

Comment: this bug was fixing 0.13/1 IIRC. You are CHAIN INDEXING. DO NOT DO THIS. use ``df.ix[0,'date'] = np.nan`` will fix for you

Comment: I've edited the question to show the erroneous output. Please check that this is indeed what you are seeing.

Comment: Changing `pd.NaT` to `np.nan` also avoids the problem.

Comment: @ubuntu - thx for the clean edit - that is exactly my output....and you are correct.  Changing to np.nan did work.  Thx for your efforts.

Comment: @Jeff - your advice will be heeded - I will never chain index again...Thanks for the tip. [link re chain indexing issues being fixed  in 0.13.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html) mentions some of the issues there.

Comment: @Jeff - getting a little off topic...but...re chain indexing - I used df.iloc so I didn't need to be too careful with indices.  In order to not Chain index, I would need ix - so would you do this while iterating row by row: df.ix[df.index[i], 'some_col']=some_value

Comment: no, simply use ix it will figure out if u pass it integers (and don't iterate - always better ways)

Comment: @Jeff - happy to give you props for a formal answer if you care.  I did run this on 0.13.1 and the sample code replication code above works with expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem also. Here's how I fixed it. "isnull()" is a function that checks if something is NaN or empty. The "~" (tilde) operator negates the following expression. So we are saying give me a dataframe from your original dataframe but only where the 'data' rows are NOT null.

```
df = df[~df['data'].isnull()]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes - this is the sort of thing that should work of course.  The question was more about whether the code that should have worked for me was my fault or a bug in pandas.  I believe we resolved (in the comments above) it to be a bug in Pandas v 0.12 that has been fixed in later releases.