# isnull: Dataframe altered when saving and reloading as csv? (v17.1)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a large dataframe and it appears that after saving it to a csv it is altered. When I reload it from the csv it's all fine, but if I don't, the behaviour is different. This is visible when doing an

```
empty_rows = df['columnname'].isnull()
```

To clarify: saving a the dataframe as csv and reloading it (via df.to_csv and pd.read_csv) appears to be altering (fixing) the dataframe. How is this possible?

Comment: your question makes no sense without data and code, also how is it possible that exporting to csv it's cut but loading it back in it's fine?

Comment: The data is too large to be posted. All I can say is that saving and reloading the df as csv seems to be fixing the problem. It's very odd. Any suggestions how to further troubleshoot this is appreciated

Comment: Well what does `cut` mean? you mean you're losing rows? What is the `len` of the df before saving to csv, after loading, how do you know the csv is `cut`?

Comment: correction: the df is in fact not cut, it's the behaviour of isnull() that is different. The df has to be saved and reloaded in order to work correctly. Is there a known bug with isnull?

Comment: presumably when you read the initial csv it converted some missing data to `NaN`, also note that without seeing your code, you will be adding an index col when you call `to_csv` unless you pass `index=False`. This question is impossible to answer unless you post sample data and code that reproduces your error

Comment: the original data is all calculated. using an isnull then only applies to part of it. Saving and reloading the data then yields the correct result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789378/is-this-a-pandas-bug-with-notnull-or-a-fundamental-misunderstanding-on-my-part